# EF: how to get ID of object while insert 2 objects

Tags: entity-framework

I have a object `author = new Message()`. It contains new Message and new Author in System. I want to save it in database with one SaveChanges step. I dont want to save Auther first and than  save Message object, because of transaction consistency.

**How to find/set  AuthorId, which is not existing in database, and save both objects in one SaveChanges step?**

Classes Message and Author (pseudo code):

```
public class Message{
public int Id  { get; set; };

int AuthorId;
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

public string Body{ get; set; };
}

public class Author{
public int Id { get; set; };
public String Name { get; set; };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must change your model:

```
public class Message{
    public int AuthorId;
    string Body;
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

And then do this:

```
var author = new Author();
var message = new Message();
message.Author = author;
// Insert message to your dbSet
// SaveChanges
```

Comment: I updated my classes with your code and Message.Id .. question: so both Ids before insert should be  set to 0?

Comment: You should leave Id-s at default value, which is 0 because it is integer, and Entity will generate Id-s for them after insert is done.

Comment: What about circular references, Suppose that class Attachment contains Message as property, so before inserting 3 objects, object Message must be assigned to Attachment.Message property?

Comment: Then instead of doing Message insert to dbSet, you insert Attachment do dbSet.